# Bit Manipulation on char array in c

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

If I am given a char array of size 8, where I know the the first 3 bytes are the id, the next byte is the message, and the last 3 bytes are the values. How could I use bit manipulation in order to extract the message.

Example: a char array contains 9990111 (one integer per position), where 999 is the id, 0 is the message, and 111 is the value.

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need bit manipulation to extract such data from a char[8] array? Is it a requirement for some reason?

Comment: Yes. Use & operator to perform bitwise AND

Comment: @threadp Nope, I was thinking I could just extract that specific value but I figured I could give it a try using bit manipulation.

Comment: @o_weisman thanks for the reply! Would I do something like this? 9990100 & 000X000, will that extract the message code? Not too familiar with the & operation. Thanks!

Comment: I think that it's more difficult to do that, than accessing each element of the array through its indices. What you're proposing do makes sense if instead a char[8] array you have a uint64_t type. If you want to extract the message code from a char[8] array, just use array[3].

Comment: Oh. I misread the question apparently. Bit manipulation threw me off. What is it that you really need to do? Because if it is a byte array, then there is no need for bit manipulation. By the way, your array size according to the question is only 7 bytes.

Comment: @o_weisman It is an array that contains integers but as characters, I want to extract the one specific section of it using bit manipulation, for example: 9990111 is in the char array, I want to extract 0, I was thinking about doing just array[3], but is it possible with bit manipulation?

Comment: You ascribed a meaning to the first 7 bytes; is the 8th byte a null byte?  Are the values in the bytes 0x39 0x39 0x39 0x30 0x31 0x31 0x31 0x00 — so they are ASCII digits?  Do you want the result as 999, 0, and 111 in 3 integers?  There isn't much bit twiddling regardless, but converting from printable digits to binary numbers does require some computation.  Otherwise, you can simply use the bytes with direct indexing.

Comment: You say size 8, but then describe a size 7 array...

Comment: in c the last position is just '\0', and it starts for 0 so 0 - 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want bit manipulation, no matter what, here it goes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void) {
        char arr[8] = "9997111";
        int msg = 0;

        msg = ((ntohl(*(uint32_t *) arr)) & 0xff) - 48;

        printf("%d\n", msg);

        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
7
```

Just remember one thing... this does not comply with strict aliasing rules. But you can use some memcpy() stuff to solve it.

Edit #1 (parsing it all, granting compliance with strict aliasing rules, and making you see that this does not make any sense):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void) {
        char arr[8] = "9997111";
        uint32_t a[2];
        unsigned int id = 0, msg = 0, val = 0;

        memcpy(a, arr, 4);
        memcpy(&a[1], arr + 4, 4);

        a[0] = ntohl(a[0]);
        a[1] = ntohl(a[1]);

        id = ((((a[0] & 0xff000000) >> 24) - 48) * 100) + ((((a[0] & 0xff0000) >> 16)- 48) * 10) + (((a[0] & 0xff00) >> 8)- 48);
        msg = (a[0] & 0xff) - 48;
        val = ((((a[1] & 0xff000000) >> 24) - 48) * 100) + ((((a[1] & 0xff0000) >> 16)- 48) * 10) + (((a[1] & 0xff00) >> 8)- 48);

        printf("%d\n", id);
        printf("%d\n", msg);
        printf("%d\n", val);

        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
999
7
111
```

Comment: It might be clearer if you wrote 48 as `'0'`.  Though, then again, it might not make all that much difference.  I'm not convinced the `ntohl()` mechanism is a good way to go, though it seems to work.

Comment: Using the ntohl() isn't elegant at all, but it works in a portable way in this case. Network byte order is big-endian, which is the endiannes resulting from direct memory copy from the array. This will grant that the elements of the uint32_t[] will match the endianness of the system running this code. Anyway, this was just to make a point: bit manipulation is non-sense in this case and sscanf() is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Given:

> the array contains {'9','9','9','0','1','1','1'}

Then you can convert with `sscanf()`:

```
char buffer[8] = { '9', '9', '9', '0', '1', '1', '1', '\0' };
//char buffer[] = "9990111";  // More conventional but equivalent notation
int id;
int message;
int value;

if (sscanf(buffer, "%3d%1d%3d", &id, &message, &value) != 3)
    …conversion failed…inexplicably in this context…
assert(id == 999);
assert(message == 0);
assert(value == 111);
```

But there's no bit manipulation needed there.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way would be to define a structure with members which are bit fields and correspond to the segmented information in your array. (oh, re-reading your question: is the array filled with `{ '9', '9',...}`?? Then you'd just sscanf the values with the proper offset into the array.

Comment: Yeah the array contains {'9','9','9','0','1','1','1'}, so sscanf is the way to go?

Comment: Yes, with something like `sscanf(arr+3, "%1d", &message)` (although sscanf is a little overkill for the single char... `sscanf(arr+4, "%3d", &value)` makes more sense).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Memory Copy to extract the values. Here is an example

```
    char *info = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
    char *info2 = malloc(sizeof(int)*1);
    char *info3 = malloc(sizeof(int)*3);

    memcpy(info,msgTest, 3);
    memcpy(info2,msgTest+3, 1);
    memcpy(info3,msgTest+4, 3);
    printf("%s\n", msgTest);
    printf("ID is %s\n", info);
    printf("Code is %s\n", info2);
    printf("Val is %s\n", info3);
```

Lets say string msgTest = "0098457

The print statement willl goes as follows..

ID is 009
Code is 8
Val is  457

Hope this helps, Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

here is an example in which i don't use malloc  or memory copy for a good implementation on embedded devices, where the stack is limited. Note there is no need to use **compact** because it is only 1 byte. This is C11 implementation. If you have 4 Bytes for example to be analyzed, create another struct with 4 charbits, and copy the address to the new struct instead. This is coinstance with design patterns concept for embedded.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// start by creating a struct for the bits
typedef struct  {
    unsigned int bit0:1; //this is LSB
    unsigned int bit1:1; //bit 1
    unsigned int bit2:1;
    unsigned int bit3:1;
    unsigned int bit4:1;
    unsigned int bit5:1;
    unsigned int bit6:1;
    unsigned int bit7:1;
    unsigned int bit8:1;
}charbits;


int main()
{
    // now assume we have a char to be converted into its bits
    char a = 'a'; //asci of a is 97
    charbits *x;   //this is the character bits to be converted to
    // first convert the char a to void pointer
    void* p; //this is a void pointer
    p=&a;    // put the address of a into p
    //now convert the void pointer to the struct pointer
    x=(charbits *) p;

    // now print the contents of the struct
    printf("b0 %d b1 %d b2 %d b3 %d b4 %d b5 %d b6 %d b7 %d", x->bit0,x->bit1, x->bit2,x->bit3, x->bit4, x->bit5, x->bit6, x->bit7, x->bit8);

    // 97 has bits like this 01100001
    //b0 1 b1 0 b2 0 b3 0 b4 0 b5 1 b6 1 b7 0 
    // now we see that bit 0 is the LSB which is the first one in the struct

    return 0;
}
    // thank you and i hope this helps
```